# MySQL Results to a File

Tags: mysql, database

How do I write the results from a mysql query to file?  I just need something quick.  Output can be CSV, XML, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT a,b,a+b 
  FROM test_table
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

(the docs show INTO OUTFILE up in the SELECT .. portion which may work as well, but I've never tried it that way)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

INTO OUTFILE creates a file on the server; if you are on a client and want it there, do:

```
mysql -u you -p -e "SELECT ..." >  file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have phpMyAdmin installed, it is a nobrainer: Run the query (haven't got a copy loaded, so I can't tell you the details, but it really is easy) and check neer bottom for export options. CSV will be listed, but I think you can also have SQL if you like :)

phpMyAdmin will give CSV in Excels dialect, which is probably what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL Query Browser](http://www.mysql.com/products/tools/query-browser/) to run the query and then just go to File -> Export Resultset and choose the output format. The options are CSV, HTML, XML, Excel and PLIST.